# Getting data from a column in GridView Yii2

Tags: php, gridview, yii, yii2

How do I get data from a specific column in GridView in Yii2 and it will be shown into the Google Chart

I used this GoogleChart Yii library: https://github.com/ScottHuangZL/yii2-google-chart

I was able to show a sample data:

```
<div class="col-sm-5">
        <?php
        use scotthuangzl\googlechart\GoogleChart;

        echo GoogleChart::widget(array('visualization' => 'PieChart',
            'data' => array(
                array('Task', 'Hours per Day'),
                array('Work', 11),
                array('Eat', 2),
                array('Commute', 2),
                array('Watch TV', 2),
                array('Sleep', 7)
            ),
            'options' => array('title' => 'My Daily Activity')));
```

Comment: Build data array of format given in chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write  query to retrieve data. I suggest you to use Active Record.

```
 $data = YourModel::find()->select('column_name')->asArray()->all();
```

Query will return multi-minesional array, you have to reduce to one dimensional with array_map function

```
$data = array_map('current',$data);
```

At last but not east, send **$data**  to your view. You can divide your array as you need.

Comment: What is 'current'?

Comment: 'current'  used to call your function . Anonymous function, you should not change it.

Comment: i'm pretty sure there's no select method in ActiveRecord. it should be  
 
`YourModel::find()->select('column_name')->column();` this should also remove the need to do array_map

Comment: $modelCategory = Category::find()->select(['id', 'category_name'])->all(); What I did was this and the page shows "Not enough columns given to draw the requested chart"